# Error with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to open my file banclub.html on address http://site.ru/products/love-is
I was create .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/banclub.html$ /products/love-is
```

What's wrong?

Comment: The rule is reversed, it should be `^/products/love-is$ banclub.html`

Comment: but still not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the incoming URL http://site.ru/products/love-is, and you want to send it to http://site.ru/banclub.html? Or vice-versa? Assuming the first case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^products/love-is$  /banclub.html
```

Note that the RewriteRule has already stripped off the leading /. This rule will pass along any Query String in the URI (?var=value&var=value etc.) to the new URI. You can suppress that by adding just a ? after .html . If "love-is" is a directory, and the user might have a trailing /, change that line to

```
RewriteRule  ^products/love-is/?$  /banclub.html
```

If you want to tell search engines and visitors to update their indexes and bookmarks, add `[R=301]` at the end of the RewriteRule line.

Comment: i think that you may need to remove the `/` before the rewritten path.

Comment: It isn't necessary; the `.htaccess` files resides in the document root.